# Embed a Google Map with approximation in my site

Tags: google-maps

This is what I'm trying to accomplish (getting a map with a circle around the address I introduce without marking the exact address)

[image]

I have the following code:

```
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp'></script>
<div style='overflow:hidden;width:50%;'>
<div id='gmap_canvas' style='height:440px;width:700px;'></div><div></div>
<style>#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}</style></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function init_map(){var myOptions = {zoom:10,center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.5073509,-0.12775829999998223),mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5073509,-0.12775829999998223)});google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);});infowindow.open(map,marker);}google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);</script>
```

That produces this result:

[image]

My question is:

How do I make the circle around the giving address?
  I know this is the code that produces the marker and I would like to remove that and make the circle around

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5073509,-0.12775829999998223)})
```

Thank you so much

**UPDATE**

New Code

```
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp'>  
</script><div style='overflow:hidden;width:50%;'>
<div id='gmap_canvas' style='height:440px;width:700px;'></div>
<style>#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}</style></div><script type='text/javascript'>function init_map(){var myOptions = {zoom:13,center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.5073509,-0.12775829999998223),mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);myCircle = new google.maps.Circle({strokeColor:'#FF0000',strokeOpacity:0.8,strokeWeight:2,fillColor:'#FF0000',fillOpacity:0.35,map:map,center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.5073509,-0.12775829999998223),radius:100;});google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);</script>
```

I removed:

marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5073509,-0.12775829999998223)})

and included:

myCircle = new google.maps.Circle({strokeColor:'#FF0000',strokeOpacity:0.8,strokeWeight:2,fillColor:'#FF0000',fillOpacity:0.35,map:map,center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.5073509,-0.12775829999998223),radius:100;})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use circle instead of marker

```
 var myCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: '#FF0000',
  fillOpacity: 0.35,
  map: map,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5073509,-0.12775829999998223),
  radius: 100
});
```

Comment: Thanks much for your answer. I changed the code for the one above but for some reason the map doesn't show. This is my whole new code. I updated on the original post. THANKS

Comment: Got it. The semicolon after radius:100; needs to be removed.